# Different values from GridSearch estimation

Tags: scikit-learn, grid-search

I am using `GridSearchCV` in order to find best estimator with best hiperparameters. I also want to check it once against a small portion of data used in cross validation again.

Here's my code:

```
print 'Load data'
iris = load_iris()
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(iris.data, iris.target)

tree_param_grid = {
    'criterion': ['gini', 'entropy'],
    'splitter': ['best', 'random'],
    'max_depth': np.arange(2, 8),
}

tree = GridSearchCV(DecisionTreeClassifier(), tree_param_grid)

tree.fit(X_train, y_train)
tree_preds = tree.predict(X_test)
tree_performance = accuracy_score(y_test, tree_preds)

print '\nDecision tree:'
print 'Best params: ', tree.best_params_
print 'Best scores: ', tree.best_score_
print 'My score: ', tree_performance

best = tree.best_estimator_
best.fit(X_train, y_train)
best_preds = best.predict(X_test)
best_performance = accuracy_score(y_test, best_preds)

print 'Best score', best_performance
```

What I do not understand is this: best_performance and tree_performance have two different values. Why is that?

I thought that when I perform `fit` method on an object returned from `GridSearch`, I will automatically perform fitting on best estimator found in Grid Search. It turns out, it's not true - I have to manually get the best estimator from Grid Search. So, where does `fit` method in first usage come from? What is returned from `GridSearchCV` if not the best estimator itself?

EDIT:
I added a result from printing these two objects into console:

```
tree GridSearchCV(cv=None, error_score='raise',
       estimator=DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=None,
            max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None,
            min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
            min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
            min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, presort=False, random_state=None,
            splitter='best'),
       fit_params=None, iid=True, n_jobs=1,
       param_grid={'splitter': ['best', 'random'], 'criterion': ['gini', 'entropy'], 'max_depth': array([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])},
       pre_dispatch='2*n_jobs', refit=True, return_train_score='warn',
       scoring=None, verbose=0)
best DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=3,
            max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None,
            min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
            min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
            min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, presort=False, random_state=None,
            splitter='best')
```

Comment: How different are they? Can you give some values?

Comment: And is the best splitter random or best?

Comment: @DavidMasip done.